# Change ActiveRecord error blank message for all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, internationalization, rails-i18n

I know that custom error message can be added in locale .yml file like this:

```
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "The field is required"
```

How do I change error blank message for all the models at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you look for is:

```
I18n.t('errors.messages.blank')
```

So to override it you can go with:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "custom message"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey!